# How can I fix this when using a Storyboard, instead of a nib?: Getting “this class is not key value coding-compliant"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting the same problem as the person who asked this question:

[Interface builder problem: When hooking up an IBOutlet, getting "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772771/interface-builder-problem-when-hooking-up-an-iboutlet-getting-this-class-is-n?rq=1)

My problem is, I'm using Xcode 4 and Storyboards, instead of the Interface Builder and nibs.  What can I do when I have the same problem?

I can upload any files form my project that are need, but it is pretty much the same as the files from the question above.

Comment: Check the the identity of the your ViewController in identity inspector. (option+command+3 after selecting viewController in storyboard). If the name of your viewController is MyViewController, make sure the identity is "MyViewController" itself and not UIViewController.

Comment: It still throws the error after I did what you said.  Should I set the Storyboard ID, the Restoration ID, or both?  It had nothing in either field before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is just the same, some configuration in your storyboard isn't correct. Xcode now contains Interface Builder and a storyboard is basically just a big NIB (XIB), so your situation is identical. Check all of the class names in the storyboard and if any of the views are connected to an outlet name that no longer exists (if you edited any names).

Comment: I did what you said, but I am still getting errors.  What else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem!

Look at the second answer here:
[Can't seem to get rid of key value coding-compliant error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876208/cant-seem-to-get-rid-of-key-value-coding-compliant-error?rq=1).

I found that some of my objects had extra outlets.  You can find an objects outlets by right-clicking on it.  Click the little "x" to delete the extra outlets.  This error will happen if you rename an outlet, without deleting it in the file and the storyboard, and recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was caused because I changed custom cells on the Storyboard. For whatever the reason, no matter how many times I cleaned or resetted the simulator, the thing wouldn't work. So I removed the custom class name on the Storyboards, so it would be UITableViewCell (which is what I was getting anyway). Cleaned, removed the App from the simulator, run it again and made it fail.

After that, I went back to the storyboards, set the custom class name again in the UITableViewCell, and then run it and it worked.